# Can we create implicit Intent to call our own Activities

Tags: android

Is it possible to create implicit intent to call our own activity? If possible is it useful or better option is Explicit Intent?

Comment: An activity can call itself the way it call others. By implicit, you mean what?

Comment: Actually I was looking that is there a way implement "Implicit intent" to call our application activities. As I read some articles we call system defined activities using "Implicit Intent". here http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android13Intent.html  an example of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please explain your situation more...
If a single Activity is there and you want to call the same activity again from this to have any refresh sort of thing...
Then its not a good idea...

All the views can be updated without calling the same activity again.
And if new view is to be generated then use another activity

Comment: No I want to call different different activities, depends on URI or DATA. Actually I want to make an application when user click on a Name then an window will appear which show category wise numbers related to that Name, and user be able to call any number on which he wants.

Comment: implement a simple list view for that...
on its item click listener call the new activity with its own listview....
and on their click listener do what so ever you want